While estimating a structural break, do we regress our dependent variable on the independent variable(s) or is it on time?
I have monthly data of DJIA and S&P 500 (BSE) from 2003-2024 and I wish to test if there are any structural breaks in the data and to identify the same. Since these are indices, would this econometric test make sense in the first place.
Thank You

Hi: Strucural break tests are on the time series itself so it doesn't matter that they are indices. The problem is that testing for structural beaks can be difficult because it's unlikely that, even at the return level, if these series are weakly stationary. So, it's possible that the lack of stationarity can "confuse" the test for a structural break. All of the structural break theory assumes that the assumed DGP is the true DGP and when is that true.
